# Create link from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

Why is the link not working if the link is created with javascript?
It only works if I make the link without the html() output

**Not working**

```
$(".link").on('click', function(){
    alert('Hello');
});

$("#link").html('<a href="#" class="link">Link</a>');

<div id="link"></div>
```

**Working**

```
$(".link").on('click', function(){
    alert('Hello');
});

<a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because event is bound when the element does not exists in *DOM*

1. Wrap your code in `ready` or move the code to the bottom of `body` so your code will run when the *DOM* is completely parsed
2. Use [`event delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to bind event on dynamically created elements.(*This will make the first option above optional*)

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#link").on('click', '.link', function() {
    $("#link").append('<a href="#" class="link"> Link </a>');
  });

  $("#link").html('<a href="#" class="link">Link</a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="link"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the calls. The element with class of `.link` does not exist in the DOM yet when you attach the handler. You must add the link via the `html` call on the `div` before you can attach a handler to it with the `on` method. See below for a complete, working example.

```js
$("#link").html('<a href="#" class="link">Link</a>');

$(".link").on('click', function(){
  alert('Hello');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="link"></div>
```